# Точное позиционрирование виджета при помощи FractionalOffset

Tags: flutter, dart

Почему когда я в Stack хочу спозиционировать виджет через Align я могу задать в свойстве alignment: FractionalOffset(x, y) число от 0.0 до 1.0 с точностью только 1 знак после запятой?
Например мне нужно задать координату по x: 0.1222. flutter обрежет значение до 0.1 
Как точнее спозиционировать виджет в таком случае?

*Upd: В принципе проблему решил воспользовавшись Positioned*

```
Positioned(
      top: alignmentY * (window.physicalSize.height / window.devicePixelRatio),
      left: alignmentX * (window.physicalSize.width / window.devicePixelRatio),
```

Answer (score 0):

## Как выровнять виджеты

Чтобы выровнять дочерний виджет в пределах его родителя можно использовать [`Align`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html) виджет.

Заверните виджет, который необходимо выровнять с виджетом Align и установите его свойство выравнивания. Например, тут текст будет выравниваться в середине справа от родителя.

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
  child: Text("widget"),
)
```

Другие варианты

- `Alignment.topLeft`
- `Alignment.topCenter`
- `Alignment.topRight`
- `Alignment.centerLeft`
- `Alignment.center`
- `Alignment.centerRight`
- `Alignment.bottomLeft`
- `Alignment.bottomCenter`
- `Alignment.bottomRight`

Вот как это выглядит:

[image]

Вы не ограничены в этих местах. Вы можете выровнять ваш виджет в любом месте, указав х, у в определенном диапазоне. Где `(0, 0)` является центром, а `(1, 1)` краем. Пример:

[image: alignment]

Для любого относительного положения `(x, y)`:

- `Alignment.topLeft` это `Alignment(-1.0, -1.0)`
- `Alignment.topCenter` это `Alignment(0.0, -1.0)`
- `Alignment.topRight` это `Alignment(1.0, -1.0)`
- `Alignment.centerLeft` это `Alignment(-1.0, 0.0)`
- `Alignment.center` это `Alignment(0.0, 0.0)`
- `Alignment.centerRight` это `Alignment(1.0, 0.0)`
- `Alignment.bottomLeft` это `Alignment(-1.0, 1.0)`
- `Alignment.bottomCenter` это `Alignment(0.0, 1.0)`
- `Alignment.bottomRight` это `Alignment(1.0, 1.0)`

Обратите внимание на изображении, выравнивание `(x, y)` не нужно находиться в пределах диапазона `[-1, +1]`. Выравнивание `(1, 2)` означает, что он находится на правой стороне виджета и ниже виджет в полтора раза больше, чем его высота.

Вот пример позиции пользовательского выравнивания:

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment(0.7, -0.5),
  child: Text("widget"),
)
```

[image: alignment]

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53716572/8387227)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Это я конечно знаю, прочитал в оф. документации. Но у меня вопрос немногого другой. Мне надо расположить виджет более точно. С шагом 2-3 знака после запятой. Так например: не 0.5, а 0.523.
Пока вижу решение использовать Positioned и пересчитывать самостоятельно в вещественное значение координаты.

Comment: @Eagle я думаю что не получится сделать настолько точное позиционирование, из-за ограничения Flutter. Я заметил что Flatter во всех случаях делает скругление чисел. Да Positioned вам поможет, приблизиться к вашему идеалу, но возможно из-за этого потеряться адаптивность дизайна.

Comment: На будущие, под кнопкой отправить есть кнопка со справкой. В комментариях используется упрощённое форматирование mini-Markdown: `[ссылка](http://example.com), _курсив_, **полужирный**, \`код\`.`

Comment: да, это проблема конечно. Я хотел реализовать что-то типо bootstrap в будущем для своего проекта. Но буду тщательно теперь проверять результат. Написал на github Flutter issue. Пока буду через positioned решать эту проблему.`
`Positioned(
      top: alignmentY * (window.physicalSize.height / window.devicePixelRatio),
      left: alignmentX * (window.physicalSize.width / window.devicePixelRatio),`

Comment: А также, можно редактировать и удалять комментарии)

Comment: спасибо. Не заметил, по привычке написал.